# Django: Making a value in a model unique specific to a user

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, unique

I have a model for a project:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to make the project name a unique value per user but at the moment if user 1 creates a name of  "project 1" then user 2 is unable use that project name.

What is the best way to go about  this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) is probably what you are looking for.

```
class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'user'),)
```

Comment: As of May 2023, the Django documentation warns that unique_together may be deprecated in the future and suggests to "Use UniqueConstraint with the constraints option instead."  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/